# Fill a combobox from a list from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am trying to populate `ComboBox` from a `List` by invoking a method in another class that will return the `List`.

```
public endStation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        startingStation.Items.Add("Test");
        Line CC = new Line();

        foreach (Station station in CC.GetCC())
        {
            startingStation.Items.Add($"{station.Number} {station.Desc}");
        } 
    }
public List<Station> GetCC()                         // Create List of CC Stations
    {
        var CC = new List<Station>();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Program.file.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Program.file[i].Number.Contains("CC"))
            {
                CC.Insert(count, Program.file[i]);
                count++;
            }
        }
        return CC;
    }
```

Comment: There is no method `List<T>.GetCC` in c#

Comment: To return a list from another class, use `CC = yourclassname.ListName`

Comment: you may need to seriously attend programming classes including OOPS concepts and then follow C#/.Net tutorials. There seems to be much coding standard issues with the above code.
1) Why do you have startingStation_SelectedIndexChanged as private?
2) Why are you inheriting Class Line from Class Station?
3) Why Class Line is not public?
4) Why can't GetCC method is static?
5) Why can't GetCC method in Station class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `List<T>` doesn't have `GetCC()` but `Line` does; something like this:

```
private void startingStation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //TODO: you have to obtain Line instance here
  Line line = new Line();

  // In order to avoid constant redrawing: we want repaint combobox once,
  // after all items being inserted
  startingStation.BeginUpdate();

  try {
    // It is line (not List<T>) that provides GetCC() method
    foreach (Station station in line.GetCC()) {
      // String interpolation - $"..." is more readable than concatenation
      startingStation.Items.Add($"{station.Number} {station.Desc}");
    } 
  }
  finally {
    startingStation.EndUpdate();
  }
}
```

**Edit:** You can improve `GetCC()` implementation with a help of *Linq* (which has been especially designed for *querying*):

```
using System.Linq;

...

class Line : Station {
  ...
  public List<Station> GetCC() {
    return file
      .Where(item => item.Number.Contains("CC"))
      .ToList();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: For some reason, it didn't get added in the combobox. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Wolfeatspotatoes: well, you have to debug: put a *break point* on `return CC;` and *inspect* `CC` - does it have items or not.

Comment: Alright I found my mistake, in program class, I ran the winform app first before reading the text file.